# How to ask for second best solution to a MIP using JuMP

Tags: julia, mathematical-optimization, julia-jump, coin-or-cbc, mixed-integer-programming

I have a Mixed Integer Programming problem.
I can use JuMP to find the optimal solution.
But how can I find the second best solution?
Or the third-best etc.

This potentially might be another equally optimal solution, 
or it might be a worse solution,
or it might be `:Infeasible` -- there might be no most solutions.

I know for a TSP-like problem, I can find additional solutions by progressively removing links that are on the optimal path (I.e setting the distances between some of the cities to be infinite).
For a schedualling type problem, I can similarly progressive set the availabilities of the timeslots used in the optimal path to be forbidden.

But is there a general way of doing this, without coding up myself problem specific methods for disallowing this solution?

Answer (score 13):

You can add a cut to forbid the optimal solution just found and solve again. Say your model has **binary variables** `x(i)`. Let `a(i):=x*(i)` be the optimal solution found earlier. Then add the **linear** constraint:

```
sum(i, x(i) * a(i)) - sum(i, x(i) * (1-a(i))) <= sum(i, a(i)) - 1
```

and solve again. (This thing is derived [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2011/10/integer-cuts.html)). If `x` is a general integer variable, things become more complicated.

Some solvers like Cplex and Gurobi also have something called a solution pool which also can do this.